# Bind ng-repeat object variable to variable in HTML

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like some help on this issue please.

I have a form called `testForm` with an `ng-repeat="question in questions"`. `question` has a `QuestionId`. In this form, I am trying to apply validation. Due to `questions` being dynamic, I'm not able to use static names for input fields, therefore I apply `question.QuestionId` to every field as name to make it unique.

Now the validation requires I do a check on the name of the field. So for example check on `testForm` + name of the field (`QuestionId`). I've tried a couple of different methods, but I do not know how I add `question.QuestionId` to `testForm`.

The code:

```
<div ng-form="testForm" novalidate>
  <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
    <label class="item item-input" ng-class="{ 'has-error': testForm.question.QuestionId.$error }">
        <input  class="form-error border" 
                type="text" 
                ng-model="childName" 
                name="{{question.QuestionId}}" 
                ng-minlength="2" 
                ng-maxlength="99" 
                ng-required="true">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="testForm.question.QuestionId.$error"> asd </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to make the validation work, but the `ng-show` will look for a variable `question` in `testForm`. How do I turn `question.QuestionId` into text first, then put it to `testForm`?

Comment: Tried `testForm[question.QuestionId].$error`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`question.QuestionId` creates formField inside `testForm` object. And afterwards you could retrieve `formField` by its key from `testForm` form object.

```
ng-show="testForm[myQuestionId].$error"
```

> **Note:** You can't get `question` item outside `ng-repeat`, so better you can pass particular `questionId` in `testForm` object to get particular formField.

Comment: Very fast response, and it worked. Thank you! Will accept answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: @J.Doe Glad to hear it helped, Thanks :)